# Couldn't connect php to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I had made a practice website for signing in using php and mysql. However, when I click to sign in (I've already created a username and password in mysql) the php file is opened instead, which isn't suppose to happen. 
My html file:

```
<form method="POST" action="connectivity.php">
Username<br><input type="text" name="username" size="40"><br><br>
Password<br><input type="password" name="password" size="40"><br>
<input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign In">
```

My php file:

```
define ("DB_HOST","localhost");
define ("DB_NAME","sleepy");
define ("DB_USER","root");
define ("DB_PASSWORD","panda");

$con=mysql_connect (DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die ("Failed to connect to MySQL: " .mysql_error());

$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die ("Failed to connect to MySQL: " .mysql_error());

/*
$ID = $_POST['username'];
$Password = $_POST['password'];
*/

function SignIn()
{
session_start();  
if(!empty($_POST['username']))
{
$query= mysql_query ("SELECT* FROM Username where username ='$_POST[username]' AND password = '$_POST[password]'",$db) or die (mysql_error());
$row= mysql_fetch_array($query) or die (mysql_error());
if (!empty($row['username']) AND !empty($row['password']))
{
$_SESSION['username'] = $row['password'];
echo "Successfully Signed In.";
}
else
{echo "Sorry, you entered the wrong username and password. Please Try Again.";}
}
}
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{SignIn();}

mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: Is php enabled and interpreted at all in your http server? Test with a trivial test script.

Comment: Why would you not hash your password and than `$_SESSION['username'] = $row['password'];` do that?

Comment: Make sure that your file extension is watched by PHP, if php is enabled at all

Comment: Be VERY careful, you do not sanitize the input or anything... This is prone to attacks... Using "admin'#" as username would log into the user named admin no matter the password...

Comment: Username is your table name or something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$row= mysql_fetch_array($query) or die (mysql_error());
```

should be

```
$row= mysql_fetch_array($query,$con) or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you missing phps opening and closing tags which control the interpreter?

```
<?php
    ... your script code ...
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

following query

$query= SELECT* FROM Username where username ='".$_POST["username"]."' AND password = '".$_POST["password"]."'  ;

also echo your query so that you come to know whether query is running or not.

then use  mysql_query($query) or mysql_error();

Comment: I'm new at this, can you tell what exactly to type when you mean echo my query and using the mysql_query?

Comment: echo $query ; which shows you what values are going in database for checking user name and password.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you used `<? ?>`check that short_open_tag=On in your php.ini :)